# Run Jupyter Notebook from a Python file

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to run the code in different Jupyter Notebooks from a Python file. 
Is there a solution?

Comment: when you mean run, do you mean open up the notebook or do you mean run the python code inside the notebook?

Comment: I mean run the python code inside

Comment: You may be looking for the execute API https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/execute_api.html

Answer (score 3):

The [execute API](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/execute_api.html) does what you want. From the docs:

```
import nbformat
from nbconvert.preprocessors import ExecutePreprocessor

# Load your notebook
with open(notebook_filename) as f:
    nb = nbformat.read(f, as_version=4)

# Configure
ep = ExecutePreprocessor(timeout=600, kernel_name='python3')

# Execute
ep.preprocess(nb, {'metadata': {'path': 'notebooks/'}})

# Save output notebook
with open('executed_notebook.ipynb', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    nbformat.write(nb, f)
```